# Select sound output from java for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi, libgdx, audio-player

How to select an audio output from Java on Raspberry Pi

I create a videogame using Java and LibGDX. The game must run on a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit. The game must also translate soundtracks throught the HDMI output direct into a monitor with embedded  speakers.

When my customer tries to play a sound in my videogame the audio streams through the 3,5 mm jack audio output even if that is connected with nothing. I use this interface from [LibGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.java).
But when my customer plays the same sound using the default media player in Raspberry Pi OS it plays normally through the HDMI output. The audio from YouTube videos plays also via the HDMI.
I have tried also another classed to play sounds (AudioInputStream, Clip and AudioSystem from the package javax.sound.sampled.*). But the sounds also play through the 3,5 mm jack.

Maybe I need to select an another output device direct from the code? Are there abilities to do that?

Maybe I need to build my project and generate the executable jar-file not on my windows PC but on a Raspberry Pi where the sound output device already set on HDMI as default?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://myrobotlab.org/content/fixing-audio-output-java-11-raspberry-pi

Comment: @Level_Up  Good idea, my customer has also openjdk-11! I try today to test using JDK 14 and JDK 17 and if this will not help I will edit sound.properties file. Thanks!

Comment: @Level_Up My customer tested the Java 17 (Liberika JDK 17). The situation is the same: the sound is only on 3,5 mm jack. Maybe the manual correction of the properties file can help

Comment: @Level_Up no, it doesn't work. I must use Java >=14 and I need to transfer the audio outup to HDMI